Why isnt the AntD form component saving the input into the browsers autocomplete feature
Im using the antd package for my Form and Input. For some reason its not preserving the users input for the next session. I gave the input a name attribute along with using autoComplete="on" and autocomplete="on" and it still doesnt save it when i submit the form.
Here is my code:
const [form] = Form.useForm();
 const handleSubmit = () => {
    form.submit();
  };
 return(
        <Form
      {...formItemLayout}
      style={{ color: "#FFF", height: "100%", overflowY: "scroll" }}
      scrollToFirstError={{
        block: "center",
        behavior: "smooth",
        scrollMode: "if-needed",
      }}
      form={form}
      labelWrap
      autoComplete="on"
    >
      <ConfigProvider
        theme={{
          components: {
            Form: {
              itemMarginBottom: 14,
            },
          },
          token: {
            colorTextPlaceholder: "#868686",
            fontSize: "2vmin",
          },
        }}
      >
        <Form.Item label="test" name={232323} id={232323} autoComplete="on">
          <Input
            inputMode="text"
            name={121}
            id={121}
            autoComplete="on"
            type="text"
            style={{
              border: "none",
              backgroundColor: "#272727",
              borderBottom: "1px solid #FFF",
              borderRadius: "0px",
              boxShadow: "0 0 0 300px #272727 inset !important",
            }}
            onChange={(e) => {
              console.log(
                JSON.stringify({
                  answer: e.target.value,
                  optionIds: [],
                  category: 0,
                  question: "test question",
                  orderNumber: 20,
                  questionId: 232323,
                })
              );
              form.setFieldsValue({
                232323: e.target.value,
              });
            }}
          />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
            submit
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </ConfigProvider>
    </Form>
);

The only time it saved in the autocomplete suggestion is if I made an api call to grab data for the form. I also tried implementing a mock api call using timeout thinking that it had to do with something in the lifecycle but that didnt work.
Ive also tried using the native input but that didnt work either
